# PANDAS .where str.count < n str.replace

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to replace a string in one column with another string using .where like this:

`dfn = df.where(df['name'].str.count(' ') < 2, df['name'].str.replace(' ', ' _ '), axis=1)`

The right columns are found but the whole row is replaced with NaN...

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"name": ['aaa ss d', 'a s', 'a f g g']})
m = df['name'].str.count(' ') < 2
df['name'] = df['name'].mask(m, df['name'].str.replace(' ', ' _ '))
print (df)
       name
0  aaa ss d
1     a _ s
2   a f g g
```

Or [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
m = df['name'].str.count(' ') < 2
df.loc[m, 'name'] = df.loc[m, 'name'].str.replace(' ', ' _ ')
```

Comment: Great, Thank You.